# Put many request parameters with GET request in REST API

Tags: java, http, rest

Is it a good practice to put many request parameters with GET request in REST API?

I have gone through couple of sites and tried to get the standard way of doing `GET URI` with parameters implementation.

Here's what i am trying to achieve : `search for all users having provided all the search criteria`.

Search criteria are like `companyID`, `sections`, `offset`, `limit`, `orderby`, `filter`.

As per basic standards `GET` request can not have `request body or payload` in it.

Will it be good way to make a `GET` request and put all parameters behind `?` in the request URL, something like this :

`GET http://localhost:8080/api/users?companyId=qwerty&sections=hr&offset=0&limit=20&oorderby=asc&filter=^[sSmM]`

I was thinking to make a `PUT` or `POST` request and send all these data in payload, and implement the code to return the desired response, i.e list of users.

If i do this i am changing the default behavior of `HTTP methods`.

Can you please guide me a way to get out of the situation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think it does not matter how many parameters you put in a `GET` request. The purpose of a `POST` or `PUT` request is not to keep your URL clean, but to aline with a REST structure.

the raw definition of GET, POST and PUT are

- `GET`: get a resource from your server
- `POST`: create a resource on your server
- `PUT`: update a resource on your server

Comment: i understand that. BUt dont you think the becomes too long for these kind of requests. One point, `POST` is also being used to `update`, where as `PUT` is also being used to `create`.

Comment: Sure you can use `PUT` to create and vice versa, but that would not aline with the definition of REST. The maximum length of a url string is limited to 2000 characters - http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html - which should be your only concern. If you want to avoid unneeded `GET` parameters you should just make sure that things like `orderby` or `limit` are optional, so you do not need to set them every time

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can pass a request body with a GET request. It's just not very common to do it. Jquery supports this on the browser side and REST APIs such as for example the elastic search API use this. They have a nice json based query dsl and you can actually use a GET request for these. Because some HTTP frameworks don't support passing a body with a GET, Elasticsearch offers a fallback with POST as well.

As for using lots of url parameters, there are two issues you should keep in mind:

1. URLs don't have unlimited length. There are some differences between browsers for this but typically it is a few KB maximum. Particularly some older mobile browsers have limitations here. It's pretty easy to run into this limit if you put a lot of things in the request and basically this means urls get truncated.
2. Long URIs look kind of ugly and you wouldn't necessarily want to show them in a web UI.

Answer (score 1):

Rest is nothing but a technique/framework/procedure.

It is no way special from a simple servlet call. It always follows the standard convention of request

**GET** - Retrieve any data from the Server. You can have any number of parameters with a limit of 256 Characters. The parameters should just act as a filter for the incoming data and they are not suppose to alter the system.

**https://www.google.co.in/search?q=google&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a**

If you see the above URL, u can see many parameters. But they are just filters to the results. They does not alter the system.

**POST** - Send some data such that it alters the system, usually add/remove data.

**PUT** - This is something special, say an advancement of POST, to be used when you want to update the exisiting data

Comment: i understand that. But don't you think the request becomes too long for these kind of requests. One point, `POST` is also being used to `update`, where as `PUT` is also being used to `create`